# Получение метода из класса

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Имеется строка запроса(ну или просто строка) ../<контроллер>/<метод>/ далее параметры через "/". С помощью этой строки нужно вызвать соответствующий метод из класса контроллера. Класс контроллера есть, проблема в получении метода и передаче ему параметров(и вообще, решаема ли это проблема и есть ли она?). Из строки запроса я могу получить название метода, следовательно, найти метод из контроллера по имени. Но методы могут иметь одинаковые имена, но разное кол-во и разные по типу параметры.

Суть проблемы: как найти метод по параметрам, если я не знаю их типа. Т.е. если вдруг есть методы с одинаковым именем и одинаковым кол-вом параметров, то как с помощью рефлексии получить нужный?

Comment: а чем asp.net не угодил в котором это все как бы уже реализовано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как найти метод по параметрам, если я не знаю их типа

Никак, потому что именно типами параметров и определяется нужная перегрузка. И при вызове метода передаваемые значения должны иметь правильные типы, а как их конвертировать в нужный тип, если он неизвестен? Так что, в любом случае, без определения типов параметров не обойтись.

Я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Делать лексический анализ значений, извлечённых из строки, чтобы определить в какие типы они могут быть конвертированы (для каждого отдельного значения таких типов может быть несколько, например строку "50" можно конвертировать и в byte, и в int, и в double, и т. д.). А затем, определив все возможные наборы типов, искать метод с соответствующими параметрами.
2. Сначала найти все методы (выбрав те варианты перегрузки, которые подходят по количеству параметров), затем для каждого из них получить типы его параметров, а затем пробовать конвертировать свои значения в эти типы. Тот метод, для которого удастся успешно конвертировать все значения в соответствующий набор типов и будет подходящим.

Answer (score 0):

> Класс контроллера есть, проблема в получении метода и передаче ему параметров(и вообще, решаема ли это проблема и есть ли она?).

вызов метода через рефлексию

> Из строки запроса я могу получить название метода, следовательно, найти метод из контроллера по имени.

названия метода достаточно что бы вызывать его через рефлексию. Даже, если там есть перегруженные методы к этому методу.

> Но методы могут иметь одинаковые имена, но разное кол-во и разные по типу параметры.

так и есть.

> как найти метод по параметрам, если я не знаю их типа. Т.е. если вдруг есть методы с одинаковым именем и одинаковым кол-вом параметров, то как с помощью рефлексии получить нужный?

это задача рефлексии а не твоя. Твоя задача передать просто правильную последовательность параметров в правильном типе данных каждый параметр. Все остальное сделает шарп.

в той строке которую ты принимаешь -- присылай себе строку вида

```
./<контроллер>/<метод>/типПараметра:значение&типПараметра:значение&.....
```

и, снова таки, через рефлексию ты будешь приводить в нужный формат данных строку.

Comment: "методы с одинаковым именем и одинаковым кол-вом параметров" - интересно, как "шарп" это сделает? и как автор вопроса выяснит, в параметры каких типов ему надо конвертировать строки между слешами?

Comment: @Igor можно в самой строке которая передается извне указывать тип этого параметра. И приводить к нему. Снова таки, через рефлексию.

Comment: @Igor в том то и вопрос)